# How to write a function that gives the pronunciation of the input vector numbers in R?

Tags: r

I explained my want in the title. I want it for 0-1000 I also want to use for loop in it. For example, when I write

```
    for n in c(6, 13, 357)
print(our_function(n))
```

It should give us:

```
[1] "six"
[1] "thirteen"
[1] "three hundred and fifty-seven"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `english`

```
library(english)
english(c(6, 13, 357))
#[1] six                           thirteen        
#[3] three hundred and fifty-seven
```

Or using `paste` to modify the `class` to `character` (or with `as.character`)

```
paste(english(c(6, 13, 357)))
#[1] "six"                           "thirteen"   
#[3] "three hundred and fifty-seven"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to use paste or paste0 for example.

Comment: @klkz you can wrap with `paste(english(c(6, 13, 357)))`

Comment: @klkz if it works, please consider to accept solution. thanks